# get events from a closed group on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

it works  on open groups, using access key of a facebook test user, but it doesn't on closed groups, tried to add the facebook test to the group, in the request doesn't show up.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug on facebook, admins can't accept test users request to closed group, eventhough the groups says "request(1)"..